# solve an equation for a given matrix and real number for a vector and its transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If we have an equation of the following form:

$$ x = c^T A^{-1} c $$

where **A** is a fixed symmetric, positive definite matrix of *$n \times n$* dimensions with diagoal elements equal to 1, **c** is a vector of *$n \times 1$* dimensions, and **x** is a fixed real number, is there any way to solve for c? Intuitively, I'd say there are no unique solutions for c, but is there any way to prove it and are there any (efficient) algorithms to find at least one solution?

I've looked into Schur complement and Cholesky's decomposition, but I don't think they are useful here. I'd really appreciate any help or tip, pointing in the right direction, since I've been struggling with this for hours and tried to find a similar question with no avail.

Comment: If you know $A^{-1}$ (or at least its diagonal elements), then it's very easy to find solutions: with $c=\alpha e_i$ with $e_i=(0,\dots,0,1,0\dots,0)^T$ (with $1$ at index $i$), and $A^{-1}=w_{ij}$, we have $c^TA^{-1}c=\alpha^2w_{ii}^2=x$. Solve for $\alpha$.

Comment: Thank you so much, and yes I know all elements of $A^{-1}$. I just don't understand the part $A^{-1} = w_{ij}$ - what exactly is $w_{ij}$?

Comment: Oh never mind, I get it, it's just the notation. Thank you! But I am also trying to look for a general solution without any assumptions on c.

Comment: Oh, and I just noticed, shouldn't there be $w_{ii}$ instead of $w_{ii}^2$ in the final expression?

Comment: Yes! It was a typo. Regarding a general solution, actually any $c$ yields easily a solution: you have $x\ge0$ since otherwise the equality could not hold. If $x=0$, then $c=0$. If $x>0$, for an arbitrary $c$ you have a solution $\alpha c$: just write the equation $\alpha^2c^TA^{-1}c=x$, and solve for $\alpha$. The choice of $e_i$ makes it simpler as it involves only one element of $A^{-1}$, but it works with any $c$.

Comment: That's a really elegant solution, didn't think of it.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have another question: would then the resulting matrix \begin{matrix} A & c \\ c^T & 1 \end{matrix} be also positive definite?